# Start an Activity if string match

Tags: java, android

I am try to implement a function for start an activity only if the name of the item inside a list view match.

This is the code, but on click, the application crash. What's wrong?

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
               String selectedValue = adapter.getSelectedItem().toString();
               if(selectedValue.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
               {
              Intent appInfo = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
               startActivity(appInfo);
               } 
           }
        });
```

and this is the Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lv;
ArrayAdapter<MyFile> adapter;

public void list() {

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/osmdroid/tiles/");
    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
    ArrayList<MyFile> theNamesOfFiles = new ArrayList<MyFile>();
    for (File temp : filelist) {
        theNamesOfFiles.add(new MyFile(temp));
    }
    Collections.sort(theNamesOfFiles, new Comparator<MyFile>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(MyFile lhs, MyFile rhs) {
            return lhs.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.toString());
        }
    });
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyFile>(this, R.layout.list_row,theNamesOfFiles);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list();


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
               String selectedValue = adapter.getSelectedItem().toString();
               if(selectedValue.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
               {
              Intent appInfo = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
               startActivity(appInfo);
               } 
           }
        });


    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        // setting onItemLongClickListener and passing the position to the
        // function
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int position, long arg3) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Delete Map ?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   doDeleteFile(adapter.getItem(position).file);
                    dialog.dismiss();
               }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
               }

            });


            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();



            return true;
        }
    });
}




public void doDeleteFile(File fileToDelete) {
    if (!fileToDelete.isDirectory()) {

        try {
            if (fileToDelete.delete()) {

                System.out.println("File delete operation success");
                list();
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("File delete operation failed");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception :" + ex.getMessage());
        }

    } else {

        System.out.println("It is  not a file");

    }

}

public class MyFile {
    File file;
    String fileName;

    public MyFile(File file)
    {
        this.file = file;
        this.fileName = file.getName();
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.fileName;
    }
}
}
```

This is the stack trace

```
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at com.example.deletelistitem.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:60)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1490)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3275)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4518)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-13 19:59:36.998: E/AndroidRuntime(14188):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the stack trace if i use  String selectedItem = lv.getSelectedItem().toString();

```
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at com.example.deletelistitem.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:60)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1490)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3275)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4518)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
03-13 21:39:57.381: E/AndroidRuntime(22701):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I solve the problem using this:

```
String selected;
selected = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: posted. Could be the adapter the problem?

Comment: I think it is better to get the String from your Array List with help of the position integer.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand what you are try to say. i am new in Android. Could you be more specific please?

Comment: getSelectedItem() returned null. you didn't select anything.

Comment: Do you know how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do the following code

```
Intent appInfo = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(appInfo);
```

Comment: did u add it to AndroidManifest.xml??

Comment: instead of adapter,use lv.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: or use this method String selectedItem = (String)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

Comment: it crash even with this method :(

Comment: where is the problem exactly ??

Comment: i have add a new stack trace use lv.getSelectedItem().toString();